# Laravel 5.0 generating app.blade.php last in source

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Currently, for whatever reason almost all views on my site generate the webpages in the wrong order.  Instead of generating the app.blade.php FIRST then the respective page's content, it generates the page's content prior to the app.blade.php.

EXAMPLE:

app.blade.php

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
some nav stuff
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

somepage.blade.php

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<div>
some page's content
</div>
```

When the page generates, you would receive a source like this:

```
<div>
some page's content
</div>
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
some nav stuff
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why most pages render like this and/or how to fix this?  As of right now only a couple pages actually render in the correct order (with the same `@extends('app')` and  `@section('content')`) and all others render like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one key piece in your `somepage.blade.php`:

```
@stop
```

It should go at the end of each `@section` in your blade templates:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <div>
        some page's content
    </div>
@stop

@section('footer')
    <div>some footer content!</div>
@stop
```

Comment: Thanks.  That both fixed it and blew my site up(CSS wise) hahaha.

Comment: move fast, break things!